# Наикрасивейший алгоритм поиска элементов массива по массиву.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, наикрасивейший алгоритм поиска элементов массива по массиву. Иными словами, есть два массива:

```
//Массив, где ищем
arrForFind = [
    objects1
];
//Массив с объектами, которых надо найти.
conditionArr = [
    objects2
];
//результат
res = [];
```

Мне надо отправить в результат все значения, которые появляются в **обоих** массивах. Также если, например, объекты различные:

```
objects1[n] = {id: '1', name: 'имя'}; //Это пример одного элемента
objects2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; //Это пример массива с условиями.
```

Тут надо найти совпатения `id` в `objects1` и какого-нибудь элемента `objects2`

**PS**:
Без использования каких-либо библиотек.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res = across(arrForFind, conditionArr)` - вернет пересечение массивов

```
function across(a1, a2) { // a1, a2 - массивы одномерные var arez=new Array();
    if (a1.length == 0 || a2.length == 0) return arez
    var i = 0,
        j;
    while (i < a1.length) { // для каждого элемента a1
        j = 0
        while (j < a2.length) {
            if (a1[i] == a2[j]) {
                arez.push(a1[i]);
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return arez
}
```

Comment: А если еще некоторое условие поиска добавить? (обновил вопрос)

Comment: if (a1[i]==a2[j])  - в этом месте измени условие

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативный вариант. =)

```
var a = [1, 2, 3], b = ['a', 1, 4, 's', 3]; // some arrays
var c = cross(a, b);

function cross(a, b){
    var r = []; // result
    a = a || [];
    b = b || [];
    if(!a.length || !b.length) return r;

    var t = []; // temporary array
    for(var i = 0, il = a.length; i < il; ++i){
        t[a[i]] = i+1; // fliping keys and values
    }
    for(var i = 0, il = b.length; i < il; ++i){
        if(t[b[i]]) r[r.length] = b[i]; // forming resulting array
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если массивы сортированы по ключу (ну или предварительно отсортировать), то можно так:

```
function compare(a, b){
  return a-b;//for numeric elements
}
function cross(a, b){
  var res=[],ia=0,ib=0,cres;
  while(ia<a.length && ib<b.length){
    cres = compare(a[ia],b[ib]);
    if (cres==0){
        res.push(a[ia]);
        ia++;ib++;
    }
    else if (cres>0) {
      ib++;
    } else {ia++;}
  }
  return res;
}
var a1 = [1,2,3,4,5], a2 = [3,5,7,9];
//if not sorted
//a1.sort(compare);a2.sort(compare);
var res = cross(a1,a2);
```